# Unsafe Pointer?

Tags: list, swiftui, subview

I am receiving this error message.

I am trying to make a subview that I can reuses to display a row in my app.

For some reason, it is pointing to the index variable that I am using to iterate over my enum in my List to display my data.

Why is this happening?  I am not sure how to refer to this variable outside of the subview.

```
 struct DisplayRow: View {
    
    var name: String
    var code: String
    var value: Double
    var counter: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(0..<counter, id: \.self) {index in
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text(name)

                    Text(code)
                }
                Text("$\(value)")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Wounds")) {
                DisplayWoundRow()
            }
            Section(header: Text("Debride")) {
                DisplayRow(name: debride.allCases[index].rawValue, code: debridecode.allCases[index].rawValue, value: debridevalue.allCases[index].rawValue, counter: debride.allCases.count)
            }
        }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide the entire actual error message? which variable are you referring to?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer<CChar>?, Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?' (aka '(Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, Int32) -> Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>') to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: I think its pointing to "index" in the DisplayRow subview.  The screen shot I have attached highlights it with the red underline.

Comment: Just realized the screen shot may have not been uploaded.

Comment: You are attempting to use this variable called `index` in your `ContentView`. However, you don't have a variable called `index` in `ContentView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ForEach for that, like

```
Section(header: Text("Debride")) {
  ForEach(0..<debride.allCases.count, id: \.self) { index in          // << here !!
    DisplayRow(name: debride.allCases[index].rawValue, code: debridecode.allCases[index].rawValue, value: debridevalue.allCases[index].rawValue, counter: debride.allCases.count)
  }
}
```

*I don't have all those types and cannot test, so typos or other errors are on you.